# SMTP authentication issue in javamail API

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-mail

```
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import javax.mail.event.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
public class servletmail extends HttpServlet
{
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException,IOException
{
PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
response.setContentType("text/html");
try
{
Properties props=new Properties();
props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
props.put("mail.smtp.host","smtp.gmail.com");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator()
    {
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() 
        {
        return new PasswordAuthentication("user", "pass");
    }
};
Session sess=Session.getDefaultInstance(props,authenticator);
Message msg=new MimeMessage(sess);
msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("abc@gmail.com"));
msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("abc@gmail.com"));
msg.setSubject("Hello JavaMail");
msg.setText("Welcome to JavaMail");
Transport.send(msg);
out.println("mail has been sent");
}
catch(Exception e)
{
System.out.println("err"+e);
}
}
}
```

im working with above im gettin d following error

```
servletmail.java:22: reference to Authenticator is ambiguous, both class java.ne
t.Authenticator in java.net and class javax.mail.Authenticator in javax.mail mat
ch
Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator()
^
servletmail.java:22: reference to Authenticator is ambiguous, both class java.ne
t.Authenticator in java.net and class javax.mail.Authenticator in javax.mail mat
ch
Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator()
                                  ^
2 errors
```

i have followed the example in

http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/JavaMail/contents.html

how should i get the output..will the above code...work
what are the changes that need to be made..im using thunderbird smtp server

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error indicates that there are two possible `Authenticator` classes which are being referenced here - namely `java.net.Authenticator and javax.mail.Authenticator` as the error says.

This is because you have imported java.net.* and javax.mail.* and the compiler does not know which `Authenticator` you need.

Fix this by explicitly importing

```
import javax.mail.Authenticator;
```

**OR** qualify the Authenticator on line 22 as

```
javax.mail.Authenticator authenticator = new javax.mail.Authenticator()
```

---

**UPDATE**

Since you are having problems with sending the mail, first check whether your network admins have given you permissions to connect to the smtpserver at gmail. Are you behind a proxy?

After creating `sess`, add this line to the code: `sess.setDebug(true);`

Look at the messages and see how far you get.

Try the other debug tips given at: http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/FAQ.html#debug

**UPDATE 2**

I've tried running your code and it works for me including sending the email.
I had to add one line for props

```
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
```

And of course, change this `return new PasswordAuthentication("user", "pass");` to your actual username/password. 
And "abc@gmail.com" to your actual email id.

Comment: i changed the code to this...it works fine without errors...but the mail isnt being sent i checked the inbox but no mail...!!what is the problem

<pre>javax.mail.Authenticator authenticator = new javax.mail.Authenticator()
 {
    protected javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() 
  {
        return new javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication("abc@gmail.com", "pass");
    }
};</pre>

Comment: hhey im still getting the same error.isssue starttls command.

Comment: Fix this by explicitly importing the required libraries. Avoid using these import lines `import java.mail.*;`